# UIScrollView doesn't scroll in the right direction

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I got a weird bug. I have a UIViewController with a UIScrollView embedded inside the UIView. Inside the UIScrollview are few images, but I need more space, so I want to put some images under the current ones. I did all the usual stuff to create and initialize my ScrollView, but instead of scrolling in the UP/DOWN direction, it scrolls LEFT/RIGHT … What is going on?

- I declared "UIScrollViewDelegate" in the .h
- My property `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollViewContent;` is connected to my scrollview in IB
- My ContentSize is declared as: `self.scrollViewContent.contentSize= CGSizeMake(self.scrollViewContent.frame.size.width, 1000);` and whether I declare it in ViewDidLoad or viewDidLayoutSubviews doesn't change anything.
- I set `self.scrollViewContent.delegate = self;`
  in ViewDidLoad

**UPDATE**

Interestingly enough, I tried setting the ContentSize and then printing it to the console. As it turns out, the "Height" attribute always returns 0. Also, note that I set the "Width" to 1500, but it prints 2000. I'm not using auto-layout.

```
 [self.scrollViewContent setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1500, 2000)];

    NSLog(@"contentSize width %f", self.scrollViewContent.contentSize.width);
    NSLog(@"contentSize height %f", self.scrollViewContent.contentSize.height);
```

Result:

"contentSize width 2000.000000"
"contentSize height 0.000000"

**UPDATE 2** If I take the exact same Code and the exact same Xib in another project, it works just fine… what is wrong with my actual project?

Comment: You need to show a little more code than that.

Comment: That's all the code I have. The images are Set up in Interface Builder

Comment: Am I understand correctly, you set contentSize and then immediately, on the next line of code read it back and this gives you different value? Are you using standard scroll view or subclass of it?

Comment: Please log your scrollView transform.

Comment: @yurish exactly. Note that I used the exact same code in another project and it works perfectly.

Comment: @fzwo What does that mean?

Comment: `NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(self.scrollViewContent.transform));`

Comment: So is it standard UIScrollView class or you use subclass of UIScrollView?

Comment: Do you have delegate assigned to the scroll view?

Comment: Standard UIScrollView. The delegate is assigned, it's my 4th bullet point.

Comment: @fzwo I tried your code, here's the NSLog:

[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]

Comment: Are you using autolayout? Does it change anything if you do NOT assign the  delegate to the scroll view? As a last resort you can compare the two projects file by file and see where is the difference

Comment: @yurish I really don't know what to look. I imported the same exact file in the other project and it worked right away. I didn't find any preference in the .plist file to correct...

Comment: Someone has an idea? I still can't figure out why...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Please check properties as shown in image]

Please cross check that you declared

UIScrollViewDelegate at .h file or not..

At .m File

@synthesize scrollViewContent;

Hope it may help you...

Comment: Hi, yes my IB is the same as your picture. I declared the delegate in the .h and I synthesized the outlet in .m